# Am I doing UDP high speed continuous data reception right?

Tags: linux, network-programming

Reading mainly the Linux man pages and posts on SO, I used the info I found to implement a "basically working" attempt at data reception via UDP.
Since I am not getting the performance characteristics I hoped for, I wonder whether what I'm doing is the proper way for thet aim, or there is some glaring flaw to remove to improve things.

As this code is not "working *as intended*", I'm not posting it on Code Review. The code is called from main(), there no extra threads in that program.

```
setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, -20); // -20 gets most priority for this process

sockaddr_in si_me, si_other;
int s;
s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
if (s < 0)
{   perror("Failed to open socket");
    return;
}

int port=6000;
int broadcast=1;

if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &broadcast, sizeof broadcast) < 0)
{   perror("Failed to setsockopt SO_BROADCAST");
    return;
}

struct pollfd ufds[1];
ufds[0].fd = s;
ufds[0].events = POLLIN; // check for just normal data

memset(&si_me, 0, sizeof(si_me));
si_me.sin_family = AF_INET;
si_me.sin_port = htons(port);
si_me.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

if (::bind(s, (sockaddr *)&si_me, sizeof(sockaddr)) < 0)
{   perror("Failed to bind socket");
    return;
}

#define UDP_MAX_PAYLOAD 65536
char buf[ UDP_MAX_PAYLOAD ];

auto timePrev = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

while (true)
{
    const int timeoutMilsecs = 3000;
    const int rv = poll( ufds, 1, timeoutMilsecs );
    if (rv < 0)
    {   perror("Failed to poll socket");
        return;
    }
    else if (0==rv)
    {   printf("ERROR: timeout when poll()'ing\n");
        break;
    }
    const int received = recv( s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0 ); // flags=0
    if (received < 0)
    {   break;
    }

    // watch the loop time jitter
    auto timeNow = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto durationMicrosecs = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(timeNow-timePrev).count();
    timePrev = timeNow;

    // time histogram code left out for brevity, it's not doing much (CPU wise)
}
close( s );
```

Context:

- a desktop PC with a little program which sends data via UDP, to remote endpoint (in C#.NET via UdpClient.SendAsync(...))
- remote endpoint: dual core ARM Cortex A9 based embedded computer

  - Apalis iMX6D board
  - 1GB RAM
  - running Linux kernel 4.1.44, Toradex' customized Arch Linux with LXDE
  - the source example runs here
- one Gigabit ethernet switch between the two (there is more stuff connected to that switch, but no high data rates)
- experimenting with UDP payloads between 400 and 21k bytes

The code running on the embedded Linux computer also has some logic to detect lost packets due to missing running counter values (not shown in the example code).

From what I've read, using a direct conenction across just one switch on my desk, despite using UDP, I shouldn't get lost packets.
But I do lose some 0.1% of packets, transferring data even at rates as low as 10MB/s (actual target is maybe  50MB/s). There is never no loss, no matter the payload size.

Also, even though I set the process priority to highest, the timing I get does not seem to change, i.e. mostly (>90%) below 400µs per iteration, but sometimes it's e.g. 20ms. Probably to be expected on a non-RT Linux kernel - but I don't know.

Also, the CPU load for the process reaches from 80..95% at ~40MB/s transfer rate with 5KB payload, or 40..47% at ~10MB/s with 1.3KB payload, according to htop. Removing the "setpriority" call does not change this. The transferrate is only "adjusted" by adjusting the payload and how much, as a result, the desktop CPU is busy from call frequency.

Here some iperf output:

```
Server listening on UDP port 5001
Receiving 1344 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  160 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 172.16.252.229 port 5001 connected with 172.16.240.31 port 59929
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec   312 MBytes   262 Mbits/sec   0.018 ms 6825/249996 (2.7%)
[  4] local 172.16.252.229 port 5001 connected with 172.16.240.31 port 60794
[  4]  0.0-10.0 sec   366 MBytes   307 Mbits/sec   0.041 ms 11871/297609 (4%)
```

160Mbit/s still has 0.5% or so loss, 80Mbit is without loss.
Using a fairly recent PC instead of the embedded board as the iperf server, using the same gigabit switch as before, has no loss at ~300 Mbit/s.

Comment: It's kind of hard to answer your question: for iMX6 the data rates you describe do seem a bit low, but there is not enough info here to have an "expectation" of better performance.

What board do you have? Kernel? Is it an official NXP distribution? Do you have problems with any other networking workloads? 

Do an `iperf` test run, maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I added the info.

Comment: Tested this also with a 2nd PC instead of the embedded board as the server, there was no packet loss at 50MByte/s.
So the embedded board is too slow for this? Or I have not found a good buffer size.

Comment: I'd be looking for electromagnetic compatibility and/or soldering or connectivity issues at this point. In my (limited) experience, Toradex makes the effort to do a good job, so if you are running their board and a supported kernel, there is probably something wrong with your particular setup.

Comment: Setting buffer sizes in Linux helped, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I found this: [Improving UDP Performance by Configuring OS UDP Buffer Limits](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Administration_And_Configuration_Guide/jgroups-perf-udpbuffer.html)

Setting the max value alone did not do the trick, though.
As I also set the default value (to 8MB in my case), I got zero loss, with my requirement of ~40MByte/s:

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=8388608
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_default=8388608
```

**EDIT**: while this helped, the CPU load of the code shown in the OP is a lot higher than that of iperf (90..99% vs. 56% as shown with htop)